# Eigenfunctions of total angular momenta as linear combinations of Slater-determinants

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, electronic-configuration, atomic-structure

In the Hartree scheme for many-electron atoms, the approximated Hamiltonian (in a.u.)

$$\hat{H} = \sum_{i=1}^Z \left(-\frac{1}{2} \nabla_i^2 -\frac{Z}{r_i} + V_\text{H}\left(r_i\right)\right)$$

is separable and commutes with the *total* angular momentum operators $\left\{\hat{L}^2,\hat{S}^2,\hat{L}_z,\hat{S}_z\right\}$ ($V_\text{H}$ denotes the radial mean-field potential).

In order to combine such commutation relations and the Pauli exclusion principle, one takes linear combinations of Slater-determinants that are eigenfunctions of the total angular momentum operators (i.e., a set of configuration state functions).

What guarantees that this procedure is always possible?

Answer (score 1):

If two operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ commute then they have a common set of eigenfunctions. In your case, eigenfunctions of the four angular momentum operators are also the eigenfunctions of $\hat{H}$ and so is their linear combination.

You may want to refer to a [related post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24106/slater-determinant-as-an-unperturbed-atomic-wave-function) for more details.